# Error in creating request to Google Spreadsheet API: field 'values' could not be found

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is my code:

```
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
{
  auth: auth,
  spreadsheetId: '1tsyo5XFh1CzlF6Xd_q1ciUQY9KDo_rWYGdrwlANBduc',
  range: 'Sheet1!A1:D5',
  values: [
  ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
  ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
  ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
  ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
  ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
  ],
},
function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
  }
  console.log(response);
});
```

I'm doing this by example from 
[Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing#write_a_single_range)

But I'm getting error:

{
  [Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "values": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'values' could not be found in request message.]
code: 400,
errors:

```
[ { message: 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "values": Cannot bind query parameter. Field \'values\' could not be found in request message.',
domain: 'global',
reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
```

Rest of the code is from same docs and I'm using it for reading from spreadsheet and everything is working fine.

Comment: I'm stuck on the same exact thing... Any help would be appreciated! Seems bizarre that it would say it doesn't understand name "values" and complain about the lack of 'values' in the same (digital) breath...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I figured it out as per: http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/7.0.0/sheets.html

You need to edit your code to read as follows:

```
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
{
  auth: auth,
  spreadsheetId: '1tsyo5XFh1CzlF6Xd_q1ciUQY9KDo_rWYGdrwlANBduc',
  range: 'Sheet1!A1:D5',
  valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
  resource: { 
    values: [
      ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
      ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
      ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
      ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
      ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
  ]},
},
function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
  }
  console.log(response);
});
```

You can also put in `'RAW'` instead of `'USER_ENTERED'` for the `valueInputOption` attribute if you want your values inputted into the spreadsheet literally as they are (instead of being formatted as if they would be if you were to enter them into the GUI).

Comment: Ok this is bizarre.  This is the code I *originally* had, but it threw a different error without even submitting the request: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. I removed the resource wrapper and it *worked* but then I tried it again later and it got the above error and only started working when I re-added resource.  What gives?

Comment: Thank you! I wasted 2 hours on this and none of the other solutions online worked. I looked through the code as well, but it didn't help as the error is thrown on the server side.

Comment: Cheers, you're welcome @Nick! I'm happy to know that this stuff is still useful. :)